Xcode repository in conflict
Since I downloaded  xcode 16, I can't see my branches in the source control navigator any more.
When I choose Repositories in the source control navigator, I see my project with a little yellow triangle right to it. No branches are shown.

If right click on that triangle it shows a message that my repository is in conflict but right over that a message appears the there is no conflict.

When I then click on OK, the message saying there is a conflict appears and gives me only a Cancel choice.

If I click cancel that message disappears as well as the triangle next to my project name. But the branches still don't show.
However in Github desktop all the branches and commits in my project show up, so I don't think that they are gone gone.
Using the git log command in Terminal also shows the branches.
Any suggestions on how I could recover the branches in Xcode?

What does git status in the Terminal say?

It shows me the current branch version and the message that there is noting to commit, working tree clean. And git branch will show me all the branches in my project.

Sounds good! So this is just another case of Xcode's Git integration being no good, which we already knew. Avoid it. Use the command line or GitHub Desktop.

Ok, I guess so. But I'm not feeling to great about it since source control in Xcode has always worked fine and all of a sudden it doesn't anymore. Thx.

Agreed, and you should file a bug. But it's clearly a bug in Xcode and it's very hard to imagine what causes it or how to fix it. You might try making a fresh clone from your remote if there is one.

You’re absolutley right! But is this a problem of running out of gas or was the engine not running properly? Anyways, it worked for me and I’m happy with it so I guess it’s some sort of solution, albeit not elegant.

I found a - not very elegant- solution for my problem. I deleted my local .git repository (rm -rf .git). Then I removed my remote repository on gitHub (in the settings of that repository scrolling down to the "danger zone" and the choosing remove repo). Third step: in Xcode I created a new repository for my project. This added my project automatically in github local and from there on I can again see my branches. This worked for me. Be sure to backup your Xcode project before following these steps. And I lost the history of commits, that's the price for this 'solution'.
